# Tree traversal in Java: Iterative or recursive?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, iteration

today a colleague and I both wrote a method to traverse a tree in java. He did it in an iterative way and I recursive. Imagine the following Object:

```
class TreeElement {
    private List<TreeElement> children;
    // Getters and setters...
}
```

And the two possible traversal methods:

Method 1:

```
void traverseTree1(TreeElement rootElement) {
    List<TreeElement> q = new ArrayList<TreeElement>();
    q.add(rootElement);
    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        TreeElement elem = q.get(0);
        handleElement(elem);
        q.addAll(elem.getChildren());
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
void traverseTree2(TreeElement element) {
    handleElement(element);
    for (TreeElement child : element.getChildren()) {
        traverseTree2(child);
    }
}
```

My question is now, which of this methods should be used, regarding execution time and memory usage? Is there any real difference or is the code so much optimized by the compiler that there isn't?

PS: The order in which the elements are traversed is not important.

Comment: Method 2: is calling itself.  I think that qualifies as recursion.

Comment: are you sure the methods are equivalent? I think the second is going to explore the nodes by depth while the first one by breadth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet that the two methods are pretty much equal when it omes to execution time. You could improve the first one by using something like a `Queue` instead of a `List` though.

However, Method 2 runs the risk of getting a [`StackOverflowError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) if the tree is large. This is avoided with Method 1.

Comment: So you mean that the second method uses more memory. But how much approximately? Is it a noticeable difference like twice or even more times the memory or more like a theoretical thing?

Comment: Not exactly. Depending on how the tree is balanced, either one could use up more memory. Too much recursion uses up memory for local variables and parameters that can't be freed though, eventually leading to a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: And your stack (which is what recursion uses) is usually smaller than the heap (which is what the `ArrayList` uses).

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about method performance, it may be in your best interest to run the code and profile it. There's really no other way anyone could tell you definitively which method will perform better.

Comment: I know there is no definitive answer for such an abstract question, but I hope to get some tendency and information from more experienced programmers.

Comment: @ItsJustTony In my opinion (and this is just a guess), I have a feeling the recursive method will be faster, as it looks like it calls less methods overall and uses less conditionals. But again, the best way to tell for sure would be to profile it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the memory usage the traverseTree2 method looks better because avoid instantiate ArrayList objects, it can also interfere a little on the performance, considering that creating objects always take some time. I would be for traverseTree2 method.

Comment: The first method only instantiates a single list. That shouldn't be a problem...